# is there a highly customizable web interface for git?

Tags: git

What i want is a git web interface which can show a limited set of information about my git repo. For example, i don't want the source code to be available, but i do want the git log to be.

Is there any git web solution which can be customized for this usecase?

Comment: You could run "git log" in cron, and send the output somewhere useful... or use a git hook to trigger an update script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, i ended up with going for something more heavyweight.

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org)

Its highly customizable, and i could set rules for which user groups should and shouldn't be able to see the source code.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- take [GitWeb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb) or [Cgit](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/), which are simple [cgi programs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html).
- put a perl script acting as the main cgi (directive Apache: `DirectoryIndex: myScript.pl`)
- make that perl call the git web cgi:

```
my $output=`./cgit.cgi\` 
or 
my $output=`./gitweb.pl`
```

- parse the result of that output to remove any link to the source code part.

That way, you control exactly what you want to display, based on existing web interfaces.